# Connect to BLE health devices through android background service

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, health-monitoring

I'm creating an app to connect A&D BLE **BP, weight** devices, please let  me know that the following queries are possible or not.

1.Connect to BLE health devices using android background service. is there an efficient way to connect and collect data reading from ihealth devices?

(or)

2.Click on Button to start scanning, find and connect devices, then collect values from connected devices?

Answer (score 1):

For your app, it requires several steps. The implementation depends on your device and app function. Generally, it will involves the following steps.

1. Scan: It is already on the background thread when you use Android BLE API. You can display a list of discovered devices
2. Connect:  It will run on background too, Android Framework will give you a callback to notify its connection status.
3. Read data: This step requires your own implementation. if you read data once, it is simple. If you update periodically, you need a background Service or a Thread(to run background) + Handler(to update UI).

A good starting point is Google BLE guideline: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html
It is little complex when directly using Android Framework, you can try third-party libs instead. For example, https://github.com/RobotPajamas/Blueteeth.

Comment: Suppose I'm running background thread for scanning and connecting BLE devices.Some of the devices will always broadcast request(example Nonin),But Now I wanna connect some other bluetooth devices(for example A&D BP).Once I Start my application,My App will detect Nonin device and Connect ,But my goal is to connect with A&D BP devices,How I have to handle this situation?

Comment: Firstly, you discover A&D BP devices. You connect with one of them. It will establish a connection with it. Then, you can look for a correct GATT Service and Characteristics, then you use get data from that GATT Characteristics.

Comment: BLE devices exchange information via defined GATT services and characteristics. For example, A&D BP devices only give updated data via a GATT characteristics which is defined by device manufactures, you may find on their documentation.

Comment: Problem here is I cant able to always detect  A&D devices from my android application through background service

Comment: It means sometimes you can find it, sometime you can not?

Comment: yeah,A&D devices are not detecting properly

Comment: So, the problem depends, it maybe a hardware problem. If you make sure that device is stable, you may implement scan function not properly. To check your device, please download an app from Google Play and test them first.

Comment: I have tested with Google Play app also,But no luck.I have posted my problem in play store review,But still didn't get response (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.aandd.andconnectwi&hl=en)

Comment: This app is not good. You should try this: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.macdom.ble.blescanner&hl=en.

Comment: If it still happens, it means the problem of hardware devices.

Comment: Hi, I have tried  1.A&D UA-651 BLE"(BP)  2."A&D UC-352 BLE"(Weight) with both apps,Cant able to detect.What I have to do now?

Comment: It is a hardware issue. Please check your device